# How to use the each() function with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input[type="file"] had multiple option and the 'div' is created when i select the images like below.

```
<div id="filenameList" style="width:400px">
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px"; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" id="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px"; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" id="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px"; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" id="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
</div>
```

I selected the 3 of images and the 'divs' are created automatically like i said above. I want to check the size of 3 images.

This is my code that i thought.

```
if($('#tmp_screenshots').width() == 340 && $('#tmp_screenshots').height() == 340) { 
    alert_success();
    return true;
}else {
    alert_screenshots_size_err();
    return false;
}
```

However this code just checked the only top of the image. I know the reason why but how can i fix this to check all the images that have same id.

```
("#filenameList"," #tmp_screenshots").each(function() {
     if ($(this).width() !== 340 && $(this).height() !== 340) {
         alert("false");
     }else {
         alert("true");
     }
});
```

I know this code isn't work. How can i fix this work properly. 
Does anyone know this? or have better idea?

Comment: It doesn't work because having duplicate `id` attributes is invalid HTML. They have to be unique within the document.

Comment: "Reused id in HTML" should be a close vote option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should always be unique.

You can iterate over images using the element selector.

```
$("img", "#filenameList").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() !== 340 && $(this).height() !== 340) {
        alert("false");
    } else {
        alert("true");
    }
});
```

OR use the same `class` instead of `id`.

```
<div id="filenameList" style="width:400px">
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px" ; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" class="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px" ; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" class="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
    <div class="not yet" style="margin : 30px" ; position : relative>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.." width="100%" class="tmp_screenshots">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".tmp_screenshots", "#filenameList").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() !== 340 && $(this).height() !== 340) {
        alert("false");
    } else {
        alert("true");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery Selector: "# your id main `div` # your id `img`

Is there your solution:

```
$("#filenameList #tmp_screenshots").each(function(index,element) {
     if ($(this).width() !== 340 && $(this).height() !== 340) {
         alert("false");
     }else {
         alert("true");
     }
   });
```